# Reorganize Postgrest Query

Tags: sql, postgresql

Im using a query on postgresql that return a result like this.

```
schedule |     day    |   subject   | grade   |
===============================================
06 - 08  |    Monday  |   Biology   | Second  |
-----------------------------------------------
08 - 10  |    Monday  |  Chemistry  | Third   |
-----------------------------------------------
06 - 08  |   Tuesday  |   Math      | Second  |
-----------------------------------------------
10 - 12  |  Wednesday |   English   | Second  |
-----------------------------------------------
10 - 12  |    Friday  |   Language  | Second  |
-----------------------------------------------
```

I need a result or reorganize this query like this.

```
schedule |   Monday  | Tuesday| Wednesday | Friday  | grade
==============================================================
06 - 08  |  Biology  |   Math | null      | null    | second
--------------------------------------------------------------
10 - 12  |  null     |   null | English   |Language | second
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

I appreciate any help or suggestion.

Thnks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method is conditional aggregation:

```
select schedule,
       max(case when day = 'Monday' then subject end) as Monday,
       max(case when day = 'Tuesday' then subject end) as Tuesday,
       max(case when day = 'Wednesday' then subject end) as Wednesday,
       max(case when day = 'Friday' then subject end) as Friday,
       min(grade) as grade,
from t
group by schedule;
```

I'm not really sure where the `grade` comes from; the above is just a guess.

Comment: Thnks, the suggestion is perfect, the query return that i want.